# Is this a travel or expats question?

Tags: discussion, scope, expat-questions

I'm an Australian living in the US and I need to renew my Australian passport, which (as of July 1st 2015) requires me to visit an Australian embassy in person for a face-to-face interview.  My spouse is an American citizen and I want to know if she can enter the Embassy with me while I wait for my interview.

On one hand I live in the US so it seems more like an expats question.  On the other hand it is about a non-Australian citizen entering the Australian embassy while I renew my passport, so it is more travel related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask it in Travel. Passport extensions are on topic here.